# e.preventDefault() is not working 100% to if/else conditions

Tags: jquery, css

This function (using option:selected) changes the CSS and HTML of 0 to simulate a kind of progress bar app. 
The problem is that it exceeds 100%. So the if statement is incorrect when returning "newWidth", or something else is wrong? Any clues would be greatly appreciated?

```
$(function(){
$('#selectChoice').change(function() {
    $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
        var id = $('#selectChoice option:selected').attr('id');
        $('#' + id + 'Item').css("color", "#f00").css("font-weight", "bold");
    });
});

$('#plus25').on('click', function() {
    var id = $('#selectChoice option:selected').attr('id');
    $('#' + id + 'Item').html(function(i, value) {
        var newWidth = parseInt(value * 1 + 25);
        var e = window.event;
        $('#' + id + 'Item').css('width', newWidth + '%');
        if (value <= 75){
            return newWidth;
        } else { 
            e.PreventDefault();}
        });
    });
});
```

A complete version can be seen [here](http://georgehowell.biz/test/index.html)

Comment: I don't see where your checking if the value + change > 100.  Logically it would seem like you would want to check your value + change < 100, if true use value, else set as 100.

Comment: What do you think `e.PreventDefault()` does? (I'm not trying to ask this in a condescending way, I'm just curious.)

Comment: It stops the event from being further evaluated in other event handlers.  It does not stop your current evaluation.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: *[`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)* is camelcase

Comment: This is why you should test your code with the developer tools open...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#plus25').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $('#selectChoice option:selected').attr('id'),
        $target = $('#'+ id +'Item');

    $target.html(function(i, value) {
        var currentWidth = parseInt(value, 10),
            newWidth = currentWidth + 25;

        //check if the operation is valid first
        if (newWidth <= 100) {
            $target.css('width', newWidth +'%');
        } else {
            //update would have pushed it beyond 100.
            //keep the original value
            //don't change the css
            newWidth = currentWidth;
        }

        return newWidth;
    });
});
```

Comment: that is brilliant !!! thank you so much 

Please see the revised version: http://georgehowell.biz/test/

if you are available in the future to help me, please send me your details and rate (likely to be similar problems)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying prevent the bubbling up the click event, pass the click event to the `html()` function; and *[`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)* is camelcase.

```
$('#plus25').on('click', function(e) {
    var id = $('#selectChoice option:selected').attr('id');
    var idItem = $('#' + id + 'Item');
    idItem.html(function(i, value) {
        var newWidth = +value + 25;
        idItem.css('width', newWidth + '%');
        if (newWidth < 76){
            return newWidth;
        } else { 
            e.preventDefault();
            return "";
        }
    });
});
```